# ERR_OSSL_UNSUPPORTED when trying to use google spreadsheet library with typscript

Tags: node.js, typescript, spreadsheet

I tried to execute this code (copied from the documentation https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/#/):

```
async function accessSpreadsheet(){
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(process.env.spreadsheetId!);
    await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
        // env var values are copied from service account credentials generated by google
        // see "Authentication" section in docs for more info
        client_email: process.env.GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL!,
        private_key: process.env.GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY!, 
    });
    await doc.loadInfo(); // loads document properties and worksheets
    console.log(doc.title);

}

accessSpreadsheet();
```

& i m getting this error:

```
library: 'DECODER routines',
reason: 'unsupported', 
code: 'ERR_OSSL_UNSUPPORTED
```

I do not understand how I end up with this. I've tried to google the problem, tried to download multiple different of dependency & tried different operating system & still the same the problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution. My google private Key should have been btw " ".

Comment: I was also using sheets api on "render", however wrapping private key did not solve issue. It turns out it is something starting with node v17.  I ended up adding --openssl-legacy-provider option to my start script.
My package json ended up like this: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node --openssl-legacy-provider server/index.js`

Comment: Unclear answer. Please, explain, what was wrong with your google private key.

Comment: Haha so weird, but that also fixes it for me.

Answer (score 1):

for anyone struggling you have to create, the service account:

[image]

then create the key inside as json, this will download the key and use that key with following configuration:

```
process.env.GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just chiming in here with my experience related to Circle CI. This error seems to mean that there is something wrong with the google private key, as others have noted.

The issue I ran into was that Circle CI does not handle multi-line env variables so well. I ended up following this: https://medium.com/@nemiga/multiline-env-secrets-in-circle-ci-ac234c075911

I base64 encoded the key and put that into CircleCI so that it would handle it all as one line, and then decoded it afterward.

That seemed to work to resolve this issue for me with Circle CI.