# I am getting this kind of error when I am trying to install npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, error-handling, node-modules

[error screenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ykgL.png)

no idea what to do ?
my node version is 18

1. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling node.
2. I tried clearing the cache.
3. I tried some random command from browser related to this issue, but no luck
4. I tried this commands type this line npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ and after that try again with
   npm install -g cordova ionic but no luch

Comment: Could it be related to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72332485/err-ossl-unsupported-when-trying-to-use-google-spreadsheet-library-with-typscrip or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394632/webpack-build-failing-with-err-ossl-evp-unsupported ?
That is use `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` before npm.

Comment: the cause of the error can be version compatibility with the framework version you using?